# AudioKit's RenderToFile not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I have an AKSequencer which has an AKMusicTrack inside of it with the output of an AKMIDISampler. I also load the AKMIDISampler with a soundfont file.

The problem that I'm facing with AudioKit's renderToFile is that when it does create the file the sound is empty/silent, or it will play a single note which will be at the very beginning of the file, as well as only playing the single note a strange sound is played for the entirety of the length.

Here's the code for the initialisation

```
    let midiSampler = AKMIDISampler()
    let sequencer = AKSequencer()
    let midi = AKMIDI()

    do {
        try midiSampler.loadSoundFont("soundFontFile", preset: 0, bank: 0)
    } catch {
        AKLog("Error - Couldn't load Sample!!!")
    }

    AudioKit.output = midiSampler

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit didn't begin")
    }

    let drumTrack = sequencer.newTrack("Drum Track")
    midi.openInput()

    midiSampler.enableMIDI(midi.client, name: "MIDI Sampler MIDI In")
    drumTrack.setMIDIOutput(midiSampler.midiIn)

    sequencer.setLength(AKDuration(beats: 8))
    sequencer.setTempo(136)
    sequencer.setRate(40)

    midi = AudioKit.midi
```

Here is how I attempt to renderToFile:

```
    let path = "recordedMIDIAudio.caf"
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(path)
    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat64, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)!

    do {
        let audioFile = try AKAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: format.settings, commonFormat: format.commonFormat, interleaved: format.isInterleaved)

        try AudioKit.renderToFile(audioFile, duration: 3.55, prerender: {
            self.sequencer.play()
        })
    } catch {
        AKLog("Error when converting")
    }
```

I've done quite a lot of research on this particular issue but I've had no luck. Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately its a well known but probably not well enough documented fact that offline rendering does not work with MIDI based signal generation.  The time clock that the midi system uses is not sped up with the speed of sample generation that happens when rendering to a file.